# Problem setting up Zend Framework to run with Netbeans

Tags: zend-framework

I am trying to get Zend Framework working with netbeans, but every time there is the error

`"php.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

I am using WAMP server 2.0
it is installed in e:\wamp

My Zend framework is inside e:\wamp\www\ZendFramework-1.10.5

I have located the ZendFramework script as:  E:\wamp\www\ZendFramework-1.10.5\bin\zf.bat

I am also registered the module.

What am i doing wrong?

I am running on Windows 7 32 bit, using NETbean 6.9 RC1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easy just add the path of your php.exe 
to your path variable 
i guess it was rightclick on Mycomputer -> advanced tab -> environment variables -> then go to the PATH variable  and append the path to the PHP.exe and don't forget to append the path to zf.bat after it and go ahead

Answer (score 2):

Just adding my bit to this: after trying for hours with wamp and now with xampp the missing piece that it took me a while to find is to change the `SET PHP_BIN` variable in the zf.bat script from `php.exe` to the full path of your php installation - for xampp default this would be `c:\xampp\php`

so `zf.bat` should have the `PHP_BIN` set like

```
SET PHP_BIN=c:\xampp\php\php.exe
```

I'd set my Path to include the right path but still no joy.  The answer above does suggest this change in `zf.bat` but I for one didn't get exactly what I had to change until I carefully examined the `zf.bat` script.

Hope that fixes someone else's frustration too.

Comment: i saw this post after 2 hours of my struggle!! thanks Alex!!

Answer (score 0):

Never tried Netbeans with the zf tool, but you got 2 possible points of failure here:

- Netbeans doesn't find your PHP binary (php.exe) - set it in Settings - PHP - PHP 5 Interpreter (it's somewhere in the WAMP directory, sorry I don't use WAMP)
- The zf tool doesn't find your PHP binary - change the batch file to use the correct binary or add the path with the binary to your system's PATH variable